# hook scripts on specific wordpress admin page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new here. I have some class code that is part of a wordpress plugin. I need to add an admin page to the existing code, and following the codex and an article I found by googling, I've added with succes that page. I want to load some scripts only on this admin page, but I can't figure out how to achieve this, every example I found is using procedural style and I need to integrate this inside a class.

I have created two methods that will hold the page creation, one is to call the `add_menu_page()` function and the second is the callback function that is responsable to render the page content. I'm unable to figure out where the `add_action( 'admin_enqueue_script' )` hook needs to be called. Here is the code I have, any help will be appreciated.

```php
// class constuct
public function __construct()
  {
   add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'initOptionsMenu' ) );
  }
// class method to add the menu page
public function initOptionsMenu()
  {
    $page_title = 'test page';
    $menu_title = 'B Page';
    $capability = 'edit_posts'; // is there any reference for this param?
    $menu_slug = 'test-page';
    $function = array( $this, 'renderMenu' );
    $icon_url = '';
    $position = 26;

    add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
  }

// class method to render the menu page content

public function renderMenu( $hook )
  {
    // the $hook variable will be empty if I do a var_dump() 
    // here I want to enqueue the scripts, is this possible?
    require_once 'test-options.php';
  }
```

Comment: How are you invoking the `initOptionsMenu` method? Is that using a WordPress hook?

Comment: @PeterMellett It's called inside the class construct.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the WP admin actions order here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request

`admin_menu` is called before `admin_enqueue_scripts`

so in your `renderMenu` method you would be fine to `admin_enqueue_scripts`, as it will be registered before the action is performed.

```
public function renderMenu( $hook )
{
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', [ $this, 'loadAdminScripts' ] );

    // the $hook variable will be empty if I do a var_dump() 
    // here I want to enqueue the scripts, is this possible?
    require_once 'test-options.php';
}

public function loadAdminScripts()
{
    // enqueue your scripts
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, will this load the scripts only on my custom admin page?

Comment: For that you'll need to look at using the `$hook` parameter - See this example: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts#Example:_Load_CSS_File_from_a_plugin_on_specific_Admin_Page

Comment: I've already readed that page, but if I pass the `$hook` variable to the function it will be empty or null.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the page before enqueue scripts like this.

```
// add enqueue hook in __construct
public function __construct()
  {
       // admin menu hook
       add_action( 'admin_menu', [$this, 'you_callback'] );

       // page scripts hook
       add_action( 'admin_enqueue_script', [$this, 'admin_page_scripts_function'] )
  }

// hook function where you check menu page before add enqueue scripts
public function admin_page_scripts_function($hook) {

    // Checking the menu page with the menu slug. 
    // You change your-menu-slug-here by the right slug of your menu
    if ( "toplevel_page_your-menu-slug-here" === $hook ) :
        // here you enqueue the scripts
    endif;
}
```

Comment: the `$hook` variable is empty if I `var_dump()` it inside the `renderMenu()` method or `initOptionsMenu()` method. I will give another try

Comment: Sorry for not quickly noticing your comment. You have to call the menu add hook before the script hook. After that, if the menu appears with the page then it should work unless the menu slug is misquoted in the `admin_menu_page_scripts_function` callback.

Comment: @abage I have the same problem, but in my case I've already defined the `add_action('admin_menu')` and the $hook variable will not be showed if I try to `var_dump()` it. any suggestion?